# does ng-if will work on img tag

Tags: html, angularjs

Does this code will work when i use ng-if in the image tag

**index.html**

```
<img class="image" src="location.png" ng-click="openModal('locationPage')" ng-model="location" ng-init="location = true">
<img class="image" src="weather.png" ng-click="openModal('weatherPage')" ng-model="weather" ng-init="weather = true">
```

**location.html**

```
<div ng-if="location">
     <h2>Latitude: {{lat}}</h2>
     h2>Longitute: {{long}}</h2>
</div>
<div ng-if="weather">
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-body">
          <h1 class="">{{weather.name}}</h1>
          <p class="temparature" ng-bind="{{weather.main.temp}}">Temperature: </p>
          <p class="temparature">Temperature:{{weather.main.temp_min}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.main.temp_max}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.main.pressure}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.wind.speed}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.main.humidity}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Try it and tell us.

Comment: Binding ng-model with `<img>` does not work. You can only bind `input`, `select`, `textarea` and custom form controls with ng-model.

Comment: In addition to The_Dude's comment: Remove `ng-model` and `ng-init`, divide your modal template into two parts (location and weather) and remove `ng-if`s, and use corresponding template for each type.

Comment: What is the point of the ng-model? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this,

```
<img class="image" src="location.png" ng-click="location=true; openModal('locationPage')">
<img class="image" src="weather.png" ng-click="weather=true; openModal('weatherPage')">
```

If you want to initialise those values, do that in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think better way to do this is you can do is $broadcast in click and $on in the location controller.

in index.html:

```
<img class="image" src="location.png" ng-click="openModal('locationPage'); $broadcast('type', 'location')">
<img class="image" src="weather.png" ng-click="openModal('weatherPage'); $broadcast('type', 'weather')">
```

and in location.html's controller:

```
$scope.$on('type', function(e, type) {
  $scope.selectedType = type;
});
```

and a small changed in location.html

```
<div ng-if="selectedType === 'location'">
     <h2>Latitude: {{lat}}</h2>
     h2>Longitute: {{long}}</h2>
</div>
<div ng-if="selectedType === 'weather'">
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-body">
          <h1 class="">{{weather.name}}</h1>
          <p class="temparature" ng-bind="{{weather.main.temp}}">Temperature: </p>
          <p class="temparature">Temperature:{{weather.main.temp_min}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.main.temp_max}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.main.pressure}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.wind.speed}}</p>
          <p class="temparature">{{weather.main.humidity}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```